# Constructing injections between sets proof

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

$\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}$
Show that $\card(\mathbb{R}) = \card(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$.

My attempt:

We have to find two injections $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

For the first injection, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ so a natural injection $\phi: \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ exists.

As for the second injection, define $\psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ by:

$$\psi(x)= \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      x & \mbox{if } x \notin \mathbb{Q} \\
      \sqrt2 + x & \mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} 
      \end{array}
\right.$$

Let $a, b \notin \mathbb{Q}$. Assume $\psi(a) = \psi(b)$ then automatically $a = b$.

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$. Assume $\psi(a) = \psi(b)$, then $\sqrt2 + a = \sqrt2 + b \implies a = b$.

The Cantor-Berstein theorem holds that $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinal as $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

QED.

Is this proof correct?

In spite of writing this, I still don't understand what a natural injection is. Is it just $\phi(x) = 1$? Or how is it defined? Rather is there proof that for two sets $A, B$, if $A \subset B$ then there is an injection $\rho: A \rightarrow B$?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You also have to consider the case that $a \in \Bbb Q \not\ni b$. Note that $\psi(0) = \psi(\sqrt 2)$ and so, $\psi$ is not an injection.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani What about if I replaced $x$ with $arctan(x)$ in the function?

Comment: I'm not sure which $x$ you mean. Moreover, you'd have to be careful about the properties of $\arctan$. I'm not sure how well $\arctan$ will preserve (or not preserve) rationality but I expect you can get all four combinations of rational/irrational being mapped to rational/irrational.

Comment: A natural injection is $F(x) = x$, when $dom(F) \subset codomain(F)$

Comment: Also, have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637366/bijection-from-the-irrationals-to-the-reals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about injections: Given sets $A \subset B$, there's a natural injection $i : A \to B$ given by $i(a) = a$ for all $a \in A$.
Since $A \subset B$, the above function is well-defined. It is easy to see that it is indeed injective.

---

As pointed out in the comments, your $\psi$ does not exactly work. However, a small modification does work:

Let $A = \{a + b\sqrt 2 \mid a \in \Bbb Q, b \in \Bbb Z_{\ge 0}\} \subset \Bbb R.$ (Note $\Bbb Q \subset A$.)

$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}x + \sqrt 2 & x \in A, \\x & x \notin  A \end{cases}.$$

You'd have to check that the above is well-defined. (Just need to show that output is always irrational.)

After that, simply check that it's one-one by taking three cases. (Which three cases?) The key point here is that $x \in A \iff f(x) \in A$. This is what was missing from your example.

In fact, you can actually show that the above is a bijection, not just an injection.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{Q} \subset A$?

Comment: @Kraftsman: Because I allowed $b$ to be $0$. Any rational $a \in \Bbb Q$ can be written as $a + 0\cdot\sqrt2\in A$.

Comment: That makes sense. I still don't see how to do the case when $a \in A$ and $b \notin A$...

Comment: @Kraftsman: The comment about $x \in A \iff f(x) \in A$ will help. Because if $a \in A$ and $b \notin A$, then $f(a) \in A$ and $f(b) \notin A$. So that means that $f(a) = f(b)$ is not possible! So now you just have to prove that comment.